# VIM replace in part of pattern

Tags: vim

I would like to replace spaces with underscores inside quotes in part of a pattern.

Example input:

```
select 
    "AA" as "Long descriptive name",
    "BB" as "Another long name",
    "CC" as "There are many spaces here"
from 
    sometable;
```

Wanted output:

```
select 
    "AA" as "Long_descriptive_name",
    "BB" as "Another_long_name",
    "CC" as "There_are_many_spaces_here"
from 
    sometable;
```

I have tried doing this with the substitute() and submatch() functions like this but I can't get it to quite work (The `\=` part is not interpreted the substitute command is written into the file). Something is missing.

```
:%s/ as "\(.*\)"/ as \=substitute(submatch(1),' ', '_', 'g')/g
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

well you were close:

```
:%s/ as "\zs\(.*\)\ze"/\=substitute(submatch(1),' ', '_', 'g')/g
```

`\=` only is interpreted as expression if the string starts with it. see `:h sub-replace-special`. You can solve that problem by just matching the part you want to replace (using `\zs` and `\ze` in my example).

This does of course not always work. Then you will have to build a string again in the `\=` part. Which would look like that:

```
:%s/ as "\(.*\)"/\=' as "'.substitute(submatch(1),' ', '_', 'g').'"'/g
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea about the \zs and \ze things. Very useful. Thanks!